# How to calculate a Truncated Julian Day in perl?

Tags: perl, date

We have been using this Julian Day calculator to give as release numbers:

http://www.csgnetwork.com/juliantruncdateconv.html

now we want to automate the build/release process and insert the build number (from today's date) into the relevant source code.

How can I replicate this TJD function in perl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
#!perl
use POSIX;

($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime(time);

$yr = $year + 1900;
$mn = $mon + 1;
$hr = 0;
print "Current Date $mday-$mn-$yr\n";

# In leap years, -1 for Jan, Feb, else 0
$L = POSIX::ceil(($mn - 14) / 12);

$p1 = $mday - 32075 + POSIX::floor (1461 * ($yr + 4800 + $L) / 4);
$p2 = POSIX::floor (367 * ($mn - 2 - $L * 12) / 12);
$p3 = 3 * POSIX::floor (POSIX::floor (($yr + 4900 + $L) / 100) / 4);
$julian = $p1 + $p2 - $p3;        
$julian = $julian + ($hr / 24.0) - 0.5;

$tjd = $julian - 2440000.5;

print $tjd;
```

Looks like it can be simplified, but this gives the right numbers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CPAN module Time::JulianDay and then truncate it yourself.

This should work:

```
    use Time::JulianDay;
    my $jd = julian_day($year, $month_1_to_12, $day);
```

And according to the link you gave you can calculate the TJD by subtracting JD - 2440000.5:

```
    $jd = $jd - 2440000.5;
```

See:
[http://metacpan.org/pod/Time::JulianDay](http://metacpan.org/pod/Time%3a%3aJulianDay)

Comment: Interesting, looks like that module has a few innacuracies

Comment: Also perl install is not under my control, so adding modules it not an option